# Checkstyle check for whitespaces at method begin

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

I have a problem with checktyle. How can I configure it for checking cases like in attached pic? I want to check for all whitespaces in methods beginning only, other whitespaces shoudnt be touched.
[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look at checkstyle [rules](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_whitespace.html). Probably [EmptyLineSeparator](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_whitespace.html#EmptyLineSeparator) is what you are looking for:

> Since Checkstyle 5.8
>
> Checks for empty line separators after header, package, all import
>   declarations, fields, constructors, methods, nested classes, static
>   initializers and instance initializers.
>
> ATTENTION: empty line separator is required between AST siblings, not
>   after line where token is found.

Comment: Can you explain which options on that rule would achieve the desired goal? I don't think that check gives us that flexibility.

Comment: @tir38, you are right, it is not that flexible. I was thinking that one can use ```<module name="EmptyLineSeparator">
            <property name="tokens" value="METHOD_DEF"/>
        </module>```, but is just checks if method definition is followed by an empty line and it ignores method content.